# Cannot preform mysql query from ubuntu terminal

Tags: mysql, azure, ubuntu, minecraft

**What I'm trying to do:**
I have a Minecraft server, I'm trying to my an admin panel so the other admins can help out the server more closely.
Right now, I am trying to make a live console. My thought was is that if I have a script fire off every 10 seconds the script would perform a MySQL query and upload the log file contents to the Database and then on the webpage is would display the rows.

**What I have tried:**
So I looked on StackOverflow and you can query MySQL databases from the Ubuntu terminal and I have tried that.

```
mysql -u username@Database -pPassword -h azure.database.for.mysql.url -P 3306 -D SchemaName
```

It does not work as I get an error

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'username'@'machineIp' (using password: YES)
```

There were people saying to edit the configs and comment out "bind-address" however it seems to only apply to the machine the MySQL server is on, and not the one performing the queries.

**Things to note:**
The Web Server, Minecraft Servers, and MySQL Server are all on different machines.
The MySQL server is a SaaS provided by Azure.
I use this database for my web server and it works fine in connecting to the server so I believe it is not a MySQL server issue.
I also use this database for my Minecraft permissions plugin and it connects fine.

If you have more questions please ask and I will do my best at answering them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like its not accepting your password.

This is the format that I use to access mysql from terminal.

`mysql --prompt="(\u@\h) [\d]> " --user=your_username --password your_password`

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. When using `--password` it still prompts me for a password. This next part may have been implied but the command seems to only be for localhost, mine is a remote server. And when using going back to using `-p` and `-h` for a remote server it provides an error. `ERROR 9002 (28000): FATAL: Invalid Username specified. Please check the Username and retry connection. The Username should be in <username@hostname> format.`

Comment: Please disregard what I have said above. I did not put quotes around my password when entering the original command. Your command worked @DudeGuy, however, I still needed to put an `=` sign for it to register but I will mark it as correct in hopes of helping people who stumble upon this.